# Instant Preview on Lyx for package symbols?

Tags: lyx

I'm using LyX, and i've noticed that when I'm using the symbols from `stmaryrd` (`\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`), eventhough they appear on Preview (Ctrl+R), they do not appear on the editor.

Is there a way to make LyX render them on the editor just like every other symbol (`\vee`,`\wedge`,`\top`,`\bottom`, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to have preview enabled. Go to
Tools > Preferences > Display
and change "Instant Preview" to "On". You might have to click inside your current math insets and then click outside to have them updated with the preview.

As far as having them behave like the other symbols you noted in LyX, see `lib/symbols` in the source code or file an enhancement request: http://www.lyx.org/trac

Answer (score 0):

of course instant preview will work, but i find it a little bit harder to edit documents this way. the editor should show the `\perp` or `\wedge` symbols just as any other symbol. i think that it is mostly a linux bug, and the way to fix it (in mint anyway) is to install the `xft` font package

so if you are using linux just 
`sudo apt-get latex-xft-fonts` (the current version is 2.1 if using mint).

if using windows you should download it from CTAN. anyway, "instant-preview" wasn't the ideal solution for me!