# Using braket package with Lyx with WYSIWYG

Tags: lyx, wysiwyg

The `braket` package defines Dirac's braket notation. To use it in Lyx, I add the line:

```
\usepackage{braket}
```

to the LaTeX preamble. Then Lyx will be able to compile commands like `\bra` and `\ket`. Problem is that the Lyx editor itself won't recognize this commands.

If instead of using the `braket` package I had defined math-macros for the commands `\bra`, `\ket`, etc., I could tell Lyx how these things should look in the editor. That is, I can tell it to put an `\rangle` before the argument (that Lyx knows how to draw) and a `|` after.

Is there a way to use the `\bra`, `\ket`, etc., commands from the `braket` package, and still be able to tell Lyx how these should look in the editor?

EDIT: Right after posting, I discovered [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80002/19017) question, which mentions the Instant Preview feature of Lyx. Although this kind of fixes my issue, it's not exactly what I want. I want to be able to specify what the command should look like in the editor, in terms of other commands that Lyx already recognizes (in the editor), like I would do with a math-macro.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are two fields when you define a new macro from within LyX, one for LyX's preview and one for TeX's use. Does this have the effect that I remember?

Comment: @SeanAllred That's right. Two fields in a math-macro in Lyx. The problem is that if I want to use the `braket` package, that means that the LaTeX command `\ket` is already defined, so I can't create a macro `\ket` in this case. I could define a command with another name, like `\ket2`, but that seems too ugly... isn't there a better way?

Comment: You may be able to \let\realket\ket and then renew ket to be real ket.

Comment: @SeanAllred That works! I put the `\let\realket\ket` command in the LaTeX preamble. I had not seen `\let` before. It defines a synonym?

Comment: @SeanAllred Maybe you could post an answer.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea :) It doesn't exactly define a synonym---I hope I explain `\let` well in my answer.  If anything's unclear don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `\let\realket\ket` in your preamble, and then redefine `\ket` using LyX's new command feature, providing LyX with the TeX code to use and the LyX code to display.

---

`\let`, like `\def`, takes two arguments.
When you say `\let\realket\ket`, you instruct TeX to copy the *definition* of `\ket` into `\realket`.
This differs from `\def` in as much as `\ket` isn't itself mentioned in the definition of `\realket` (IIRC, it's a one-level-deep copy), whereas `\def\realket\ket` would simply have `\realket` 'pointing to' `\ket`, where `\ket`s definition could change at any time.
Since the definition of `\ket` from `braket` is saved into `\realket`, you are free to redefine `\ket` to whatever you please :)

Comment: @becko You're most welcome :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use LyX's new command feature in this context? Do I still have to define a macro in LyX or can I just `\renewcommand{\ket}[1]{\realket{\#1}}`? The latter did not work for me...

Comment: @Suppenkasper At this point, you should post a new question js provide a link back to this one for context.

Answer (score 1):

This inconvenience is finally solved in From LyX-2.4.0-beta3 (format 616). You can just fill the LyX box to define how the macro displays in LyX and leave the TeX box empty, and things will work as expected.

[image: lyx macro screenshot]

As written in the LyX source code:

```
* Format incremented to 616: Do not output LaTeX for a macro if the LaTeX part is empty
- This allows the user to define the LyX display for LaTeX commands
  that are already defined (e.g., in user preamble or a package).
```